# Push notifications not working after portal changes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, push-notification

I recently changed the following things on our Apple Dev portal.  I asked this before but wasn't very clear on what I had changed.

I'm using:
- Phonegap 2.1.0
- iOS 6 min 4.3
- XCode 4.5

I am using only development certificates for testing.  We aren't testing the production certificates yet.

- App ID's : Enabled Production Push notifications.
- Provisioning: Added a distribution entry and removed 1 device from the profile.
- I also changed the Product/Bundle Name in the main target.
- I downloaded the new certificates and installed them.

I get a token perfectly, it registers for notifications.  I don't get an error from Apple feedback.  Is there anything that I changed that would effect push notifications?  Would I ever have to re-download anything but the provision profile after making changes?  I'm testing on an iPhone 4, I've rebooted several times and switched notifications on/off.

I also added the AppStore build scheme if that has any effect.

Comment: I'm using Moons APNS which was working fine, we even get feedback when we use fake tokens.  The real token doesn't return feedback and also doesn't receive a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well they started working after I changed the Bundle Display name back to the original name, but I don't think that's what fixed it, I had done that before.